# How to get value different than filtered on one from one of two columns in SQL

Tags: sql

I have crossjoined a table on itself to get all possible scores so I have a table that looks like

```
id   | id2   | score
'1'  | '2'   | .5
'1'  | '3'   | .4
'2'  | '3'   | .6
```

and I want just the values involving id = '2'. to do so I filter on id=='2' or id2=='2'.  Now I want to grab the id other than '2' (this won't always be an int in the string).  The desired output would be

```
id | score
'1'| .5
'3'| .6
```

Comment: tag your sql engine.

Answer (score 0):

One method is:

```
select (case when id = 2 then id2 else id end) as id, score
from t
where 2 in (id, id2);
```